# python - regex on "°F" or "°C", and "-40" like symbols

Tags: python, regex

In python I am trying replace a text file in the following way:

> İmparatorluk zirvesini 15 ve 17'nin arasında, özelikle I. Süleyman
>   döneminde 10.000'lerde yaşadı.

->

> "İmparatorluk" "zirvesini" "15" "ve" "17'nin" "arasında",
>   "özelikle" "I." "Süleyman" "döneminde" "10.000'lerde"
>   "yaşadı" "."

With the following code, I can manage to do the conversion above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re, io, os

def create_data(txt_file):
        with io.open (txt_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
                text=myfile.read()

        replacer = re.compile(r"([IVXLCDM]+\.|-[\d\.-]+(?:'\w+)?|[\w'-]+|[.,!?;()%])", re.UNICODE)

        output_text = replacer.sub(r'"\1"', text).replace('""','" "')

        file_name = os.getcwd() + "/" + txt_file[:-4] + ".data"
        print file_name
        text_file = open(file_name, "w")
        text_file.write(output_text.encode('utf8'))
        text_file.close()
```

But for another text;

> Doğu Anadolu'da sıcaklıklar −30 °C ve −40 °C'ye (−22 °F ve −40 °F)
>   kadar düşebilir ve kar yılın en az 120 günü yerde kalır.

the conversion occurs as the following:

> "Doğu" "Anadolu'da" "sıcaklıklar" −"30" °"C" "ve" −"40" °"C'ye"
>   "("−"22" °"F" "ve" −"40" °"F" ")" "kadar" "düşebilir" "ve" "kar"
>   "yılın" "en" "az" "120" "günü" "yerde" "kalır" "."

But I want the conversion to be occured as the following:

> "Doğu" "Anadolu'da" "sıcaklıklar" "-30" "°C" "ve" "−40" "°C'ye" "("
>   "-22" "°F" "ve" "−40" "°F" ")" "kadar" "düşebilir" "ve" "kar" "yılın"
>   "en" "az" "120" "günü" "yerde" "kalır" "."

How can I fix my code or regex to achieve that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex: `^|$|` will match the start of the string, the end of the string, or single spaces. You can use that to split the string, then join it with the necessary quotes.

Here's the code I'd use for JavaScript; I hope you can figure out how to do the same in python.

```
"\"" + string.split(new RegExp("^|$| ", "g")).join("\" \"") + "\"";
```